# JDA 5 embed addreaction is incompatible types error

Tags: discord-jda

I have imported net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.emoji.Emoji and below is the code written

```
EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
                embed.setColor(Color.green);
                event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("").setEmbeds(embed.build()).queue(message -> {
                    message.addReaction("✔").queue();
                });
```

When running the code above, the error **java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.emoji.Emoji** occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an instance of [`Emoji`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/emoji/Emoji.html). It offers various factory methods:

- [Emoji.fromCustom](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/emoji/Emoji.html#fromCustom(java.lang.String,long,boolean)) Can be used to create a custom emoji (those you upload with custom images)
- [Emoji.fromUnicode](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/emoji/Emoji.html#fromUnicode(java.lang.String)) Can be used to create a unicode emoji (such as smiley or similar)
- [Emoji.fromFormatted](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/emoji/Emoji.html#fromFormatted(java.lang.String)) Can be used to *parse* any emoji from the mention format (relevant for messages)

In your case, the string you have is a unicode emoji. To use it as a reaction, simply wrap it in `Emoji.fromUnicode(...)`.

Example: `message.addReaction(Emoji.fromUnicode("✔")).queue()`

Note that you should also make sure that your files and compiler use UTF-8 if you directly paste emoji this way. To avoid issues with encoding you can use the codepoint notation instead. You can find the codepoint notation by searching for `✔ unicode` on your search engine of choice.

Example: `message.addReaction(Emoji.fromUnicode("U+2713")).queue()`

For performance reasons, it is recommended to store these emoji instances in static final fields.

```java
public class Emojis {
  public static final Emoji CHECKMARK = Emoji.fromUnicode("U+2713");
}
```

Then you can just use it like this: `message.addReaction(Emojis.CHECKMARK).queue()`.